# Permission Limitation in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, online

I am getting below error while providing Library/Folder access to others in SharePoint Online 2016, Please suggest your thoughts and solutions to provide access to one Time.

Error message :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How many items in the folder? How many items have unique permissions in this folder?

Please make sure the list view is not exceed the list view threshold. 5000 is the maximum number of list or library items that a database operation, such as a query, can process at one time. Operations that exceed this limit are blocked.

Reference: [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Comment: Thank You, Yes we have around 14500 items in the library. Any other solution or any third-party tool can this task?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limitsnvite%20to%20SharePoint%20site%20collections.): "Unique security scopes per list or library - 5,000. For large lists, design to have as few unique permissions as possible."

Note, this is about the number of unique permissions, not the total number of items. By unique permissions, each individual item that has been shared will (usually) count as a unique permission. If 20 items are in a folder, and the folder has been shared, that's still just one unique permission.

Unfortunately, there's no simple answer here: restructure the library into multiple libraries, or add folders and restructure content into the folders (moving into folders won't help on its own, this would only help if the unique permission on the individual items could be removed, and instead the permissions could be applied to the folder.)

Side note: the version of SharePoint Online is just "SharePoint Online", not 2016. 2016 is a reference to an instance of SharePoint running on your own servers, not in Office 365.

Comment: Thank You for the help Mike, Since we have migrated data from Atlassian Source to SharePoint using 3rd party tool with permission levels.  While migration we have added a few AD groups to the permission list. Now when we try to add any AD groups the libraries it is throwing this error. Do we have any utility tools to add AD groups for members ?

Comment: Tools to add AD groups to the library? PowerShell is the big one, though I'm sure there are other 3rd party tools that can help with permissions as well. But any of the tools will need to deal with the limits you're hitting, which means getting rid of some of the unique permissions first.